# What is more efficient mutableStateOf or mutableStateFlow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow, mutablestateof

I would to like to use `MutableStateFlow` in Compose components.

```
    var hasReadCode by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var hasReadCodeFlow = remember { MutableStateFlow(hasReadCode) }
```

I have problem with `mutableStateOf` it is feature with QRcode reader, when it reads code this value goes with true, false, true with 100ms and it make double navigation back.
So I had to make work around with flow and `.debounce`, but as far as I know I should use flow in viewmodels only.

```
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = "handleReadCode") {
        hasReadCodeFlow
            .debounce(600L)
            .collectLatest { hasReadCode ->
                if (hasReadCode) {
                    handleDataDetection(events, code, navigation)
                }
            }
    }
```

```
                QRCode { result ->
                                code = result
                                hasReadCode = true
                                hasReadCodeFlow.value = true
                            }
```

Can I someone improve my code?
In my case I could delete `mutableStateOf` and stay with flow.

Greetings,
Chris

Comment: I think you should not use MutableStateFlow in your composable. You should handle your flows in your view model and than give it as a state into your component